# The method gethSvanslängd(String) in the type Hund is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, methods

i made a program to manage a dog list but i get 1 error:
The method gethSvanslängd(String) in the type Hund is not applicable for the arguments ()
i really don't understand how to fix it.
thanks

Here's my code:

```
public class Hund {

    private String HundNamn;
    private String HundRas;
    private int HundÅlder;
    private double HundVikt;
    private double HundSvansLängd;
    private String tax = "tax";

    Hund(String namn, String ras, int ålder, double vikt){ 
        HundNamn = namn;
        HundRas = ras;
        HundÅlder = ålder;
        HundVikt = vikt;
    }

    public double gethSvanslängd(String HundRas) {
        if (HundRas.equals(tax)) { 
            HundSvansLängd = 3.7;
        }
        else {
            HundSvansLängd = (HundÅlder*HundVikt)/10;
        }
        return HundSvansLängd;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return HundNamn+" "+HundRas+" "+HundÅlder+" years old "+HundVikt+" kg "+"tail lenght= "+HundSvansLängd;
    }

    public String getNamn() {
        return HundNamn;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Kennel {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int val;
    ArrayList<Hund> HundLista= new ArrayList<Hund>();
        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Tryck 1 för att lägga till en hund");
            System.out.println("Tryck 2 för att lista hundarna");
            System.out.println("Tryck 3 för att ta bort en hund");
            System.out.println("Tryck 4 för att avsluta programmet");
            val=sc.nextInt();
        }
if(val==1){
    System.out.println("Hundens namn:");
    String namn = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Hundens ras: ");
    String ras = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Hundens ålder: ");
    int ålder=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Hundens vikt: ");
    double vikt=sc.nextDouble();
    Hund nyhund = new Hund(namn, ras, ålder, vikt);
    HundLista.add(nyhund);
}

else if(val==2){
    System.out.println("Ange svanslängd:");
    double minstasvanslängd=sc.nextDouble();
    for(int h=0;h<HundLista.size();h++){
        String HundRas = "test";
        if(HundLista.get(h).gethSvanslängd(HundRas)>=minstasvanslängd){
            System.out.println(HundLista.get(h));
        }
    }
}
else if(val==3){
    System.out.println("Ange hundens namn:");
    String radera= sc.nextLine();
    for(int x=0;x<HundLista.size();x++){
        if (HundLista.get(x).equals(radera)){
            HundLista.remove(x);
            System.out.println("Hunden har tagits bort");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Hundens namn är inte korrekt");
        }
    }

}
else if(val==4){
    System.exit(0);
}


}
```

}

Comment: You call gethSvanslängd with the wrong arguments number

Comment: What exactly you don't understand in error message? It says that you try invoke method that have string parameter without supplying any argument.

Answer (score 2):

`gethSvanslängd(String HundRas)` must take an argument of type `String`.

You call it with no arguments, like this: `gethSvanslängd()`.

Provide it a `String` argument.

Say you have a `String`, `String someString`.

Then you want to call `gethSvanslängd(someString)`.

Comment: i don't get it sorry...can't you show me please?

Comment: ok but:
1.if i write gethSvanslängd(HundRas) i still get an error (HundRas cannot be resolved to a variable)
2. i do have a string HundRas in the class Hund.java, isn't this one that i'm supposed to use?
3. if a provide a string HundRas before calling the method i get a huge error

Comment: You need to reference `Hund.HundRas`. You are trying to access it via class `Kennel`. You need a `Hund.getHundRas()` method which returns `hundRas`. and you need to call `getHundRas()` on an instance of `Hund` to get the `String` (`hundRas`) that you are trying to access.

Comment: and what error do you get? Saying you get an error is not nearly as informative to me as telling me what the error is.

Comment: ok if in the kennel class i write if(HundLista.get(h).gethSvanslängd(String HundRas)>=minstasvanslängd) i get String cannot be resolved to a variable
 Syntax error on token "HundRas", delete this token

if i write if(HundLista.get(h).gethSvanslängd(HundRas)>=minstasvanslängd) i get HundRas cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Declare and initialize the variable before you try to use it. Place `String HundRas = "test";` before `if(HundLista.get(h).gethSvanslängd(HundRas)>=minstasvanslängd)`

Comment: done and now the whole code is underlined with red dots and if i run it i get "Unreachable code"

Comment: Update the question with your exact code, with that change. That code change should not have resulted in that compilation error.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you late. I overlooked something in your original code. My apologies. Your `for(;;)` loop will never complete. `for(;;)` is equivalent to `while(true)` and you never `break` out of the loop, so everything after your `for(;;)` loop is unreachable code, which, in Java, is a compilation error by language definition.